# IME Keycode Next not working

Tags: android

In my application there is two edit text one for user name and the other for password with vertical orientation.
When tap in the first edit text there see ime option 'Next'.
But tapping on it not goes the cursor to the next edit field.

Below am giving the layout.

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
>     android:paddingRight="20dp"
>     android:paddingTop="50dp" >
>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/email_mob_edit"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:hint="E-MAIL"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
>         android:singleLine="true"
>         android:background="@drawable/edit_text_top_boarder"
>         android:paddingLeft="5dp"
>         android:textColor="#2c2a29"
>         android:inputType="textEmailAddress">
>     </EditText>       <ImageView
>        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="@drawable/table_cell_seperator"/>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/password_edit"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:inputType="textPassword" 
>         android:hint="PASSWORD"
>         android:singleLine="true"
>         android:textColor="#2c2a29"
>         android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bottom"
>         android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/forgot_password_text"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     android:textSize="16sp"
>     android:text="Glemt Password?"
>     android:textColor="#ffff"/>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/invalid_alert_text"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:text="Husk at udfylde e-mail/mobilnummer og password"
>     android:visibility="invisible" 
>     android:textSize="16sp"
>     android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/login_button"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>     android:background="@drawable/login_xml"
>     android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

jibysthomas

write this property in the edittext property

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password_edit"
```

and replce the id  @+id/password_edit to the edittext to which you want to jump on press of next

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/rest"//Targeted id
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```